# How do you debug polymer style mixins?

Tags: polymer-1.0

Browsers have strong tools that help you debug css styles of your html elements. But it is very tedious to find out where a style came from in a polymer element with custom styles and style mixins. What is your experience? How do you best read those long style selectors? How can you make a connection to the source files?

Example:

Outcome of `my-element{--paper-input-container-input{font-size:14px};}`

Any chance to bring the outcome in relation to the source?

[image]

Comment: try setting `useNativeCSSProperties` to true. [Docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings)

Comment: I would also recommend setting `dom` to `shadow` and debugging in Chrome to get a better idea how a browser with native Shadow DOM support will apply the mixins. The CSS shim in Shady DOM accomplishes what it can by creating on the fly a lot of the high-specificity styles as you see in your screenshot.

While not directly applicable to your question, here is some discussion about a related issue: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3205